# How do I perform a confusion matrix calculation on my already custom trained YOLOv3 Tiny model?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, confusion-matrix, darknet

I just finished training a yolov3 tiny model via google colab. I need the information regarding its accuracy in detection. How do I perform the evaluation for this model in terms of confusion matrix?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You do not use a confusion matrix for object detection because it is not a classification problem. You should use the AP/mAP.